# Am trying to run this code ,but its saying tkinter has no attribute "Tk()",am using pycharm,both the Tk() and mainloop(). Thank you

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, python-import

Am trying to run this code ,but its saying tkinter has no attribute “Tk()”,am using pycharm,both the Tk() and mainloop(). Thank you

```
import tkinter

def main():
    
    main_window=tkinter.Tk() #here
    
    tkinter.mainloop() #and here
main()
```

Comment: Did you name your file `tkinter.py` or something similar

Comment: Have you installed `tkinter` as part of your python environment?

Comment: @CoolCloud  thanks bro ,I named a file tkinter.py so thats where the problem is . Thank you so much

Comment: @SoumikRakshit the problem is that I named a file as tkinter.py